# $\omega=-ydx+xdy $ is a left-invariant $1$-form on $S^1$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, differential-forms

[image]
[image]

---

**Source:** "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu, p207, p199.

How do I show that $\omega=-y dx + x dy $ is a left-invariant $1$-form on $S^1$?

I have to show that for all $ g, x \in S^1$,  we have $l^*_g(\omega_{gx})=\omega_x$. But, what is $\omega_{gx}$? How do I compute $l^*_g(\omega_{gx})$?

*Edit (definition of $\omega_x$):* A covector $\omega_x$ at $x$ is a linear function $T_xS^1\to \Bbb R$.

Comment: Perhaps the notation $\omega_x$ is introduced a bit earlier in the text. The given information is insufficient to know what $\omega_x$ means.

Comment: @Brahadeesh  Thanks!   a covector $\omega_x$ at $x$ is a linear function $T_xS_1\to \Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks for adding the source :) Can you also edit the definition of $\omega_x$ into the body of the question, rather than have it in the comments? That would be better in my opinion.

Comment: Certainly！ thank you very much

Comment: To start can you do exercise 17.3?

Comment: @cmk   I am not sure， particularly at the appearance of $ \omega_{gx}$

Comment: Example 17.16 on page 198 is very similar.

Comment: @Brahadeesh  Thanks    I am still  confused about $\omega_{gx}$

Comment: @Clin As I understand it, $\omega_{gx}$ is found by "evaluating" $\omega$ at the point $gx$. That is, suppose $x = (a,b) \in S^1$, $g = (\cos t, \sin t) \in S^1$. Then, $gx = \bigl( (\cos t)a - (\sin t)b, (\sin t)a + (\cos t)b \bigr)$. Given that $\omega = -ydx + xdy$, we simply have $\omega_x = -b dx + a dy$ and $\omega_{gx} = -\bigl( (\sin t)a + (\cos t)b \bigr)dx + \bigl( (\cos t)a - (\sin t)b \bigr)dy$.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure of the notations that Tu uses in his book, so you may have to "translate" some of the following arguments into his language.

We are asked to verify that $\omega = -ydx + xdy$ is a left-invariant $1$-form on $S^1$, i.e. that $(l_g)^*\omega = \omega$ for all $g \in S^1$.

Now, in general, if $f \colon M \to N$ is a smooth map of manifolds and $\omega = \sum_i a_i dy_i$ is a $1$-form on $N$, then the pullback $f^*\omega$ is the $1$-form on $M$ given by $f^*\omega = \sum_i (a_i \circ f)\, d(y_i \circ f)$. So, we need to compute the various terms in this expression for our specific $\omega$ and $f$ and check that $f^*\omega = \omega$.

So, fix $g = (\cos t, \sin t)$, and let $(x,y) \in S^1$ be an arbitrary point. We first compute the coefficients ($a_i \circ f$):
$$
\bigl((-y) \circ l_g\bigr)(x,y) = (-y)\bigl( (\cos t)x - (\sin t)y, (\sin t)x + (\cos t)y \bigr) = -(\sin t)x - (\cos t)y
$$
$$
\bigl((x) \circ l_g\bigr)(x,y) = (x)\bigl( (\cos t)x - (\sin t)y, (\sin t)x + (\cos t)y \bigr) = (\cos t)x - (\sin t)y.
$$
Next, we compute $d(y_i \circ f)$. The expressions $y_i \circ f$ are, in our case, just $x \circ l_g$ and $y \circ l_g$. Luckily, we have already computed these expressions right above:
$$
d(x \circ l_g) = d\bigl( (\cos t)x - (\sin t)y \bigr) = (\cos t) dx - (\sin t) dy
$$
$$
d(y \circ l_g) = d\bigl( (\sin t)x + (\cos t)y \bigr) = (\sin t) dx + (\cos t) dy.
$$

We can now write down the expression for $f^*\omega$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
(l_g)^*\omega &= \bigl( -(\sin t)x - (\cos t)y \bigr) \cdot \bigl( (\cos t) dx - (\sin t) dy \bigr) + \bigl( (\cos t)x - (\sin t)y \bigr) \cdot \bigl( (\sin t) dx + (\cos t) dy \bigr)\\ &= -ydx + xdy = \omega.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you all so much.   Why can't we compute $   l^*_g(\omega_{gx}) $ through this approach?  Thanks a million

Comment: @Clin Glad to be of help! I'm sorry, I'll be able to get back to this question only after a few days at least, I have some other urgent work coming up. To make a small comment regarding your question, I believe that we can compute $l_g^*(\omega_{gx})$ in the same way, but I'll have to write things out to convince myself first.